# Multiple transaction create in accounts module using a laravel package

Tags: laravel, api, transactions, package, accounting

I am creating a double entry accounts website in laravel, transaction sale, purchase and cash or bank etc. And i have build the api for an payment website using laravel accounting package [eloquent-ifrs](https://github.com/ekmungai/eloquent-ifrs#eloquent-ifrs%5D) , When I create api for add transaction, these trancation is multiple types.

I have all trasaction created expect 'contra entry' transaction because in this transaction main account type not valid for double entry for line item post ledgers.example:-

```php
$contraEntry = ContraEntry::create([
    'entity_id' => $entity,
    'account_id' => $bankAccount->id,
]);

$zeroVat  = DB::table('ifrs_vats')->where('entity_id', $entity)->whereNull('account_id')->first();

$assetAccount = Account::where('account_type', 'BANK')->first();

$contraEntryLineItem = LineItem::create([
    'vat_id' =>  $zeroVat->id,
    'account_id' => $assetAccount->id,
    'vat_account_id' =>  $zeroVat->account_id
```

In this example of code contraEntry transaction created after that lineItem not created. Because A Transaction Main Account cannot be one of the Line Item Accounts.

I have sent parameter account_id for create first `ContraEntry::create([])` and required `account_type = "BANK"` and `account_type= "BANK"` required in `LineItem::create([])` but exist account id can't be send showing [this error](https://prnt.sc/0vSfW5RUaObg).

If any one have already worked on this Eloquent IFRS laravel package or working on this "Eloquent IFRS" accounting package.Help me out I really appreciate.